# In python, how to access a function of an imported class inside an imported class as it gives attribute error?

Tags: python

I have imported a class module and inside that class module I have another class module but when I try to access that I get the error as

> AttributeError: 'class_name1' object has no attribute 'function_name2_1'

Example code for detail:

main.py

```
from FOLDER import File_name1 as a
b = a.class_name1('aa')
```

**EDITED, The full code is like this**
File_name1.py

```
class class_name1:
    def __init__(self, name)
        self.varname = name
        if (name == 'aa')
            from FOLDER.File_name2 import class_name2
            print('a')
        if (name == 'bb')
            from FOLDER.File_name3 import class_name3
```

File_name2.py

```
class class_name2:
    def __init__(self, name)
        self.varname = name
    def function_name2_1(self):
        print('Something')
```

When I run main.py program I get output

> a

as expected. But if I add the line b.function_name2_1() ie.
main.py

```
from FOLDER import File_name1 as a
b = a.class_name1('aa')
b.function_name2_1()
```

I get the above error.

> File
>   "C:/Users/Karthik/Desktop/PROGRAMMING/Testing/main.py", line 3, in 
>       b.function_name2_1()
>
> AttributeError: 'class_name1' object has no attribute 'function_name2_1'

I don't know how to resolve this. Could anyone please help me?

Comment: This... isn't something that can work. Importing a class into another class doesn't make it magically get all its methods. Are you perhaps looking for inheritance?

Comment: You have several levels of namespace issues here.  And more importantly, likely have a severe case of XY.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Yes, I want to inherit the class_name2 to variable b after it inherits or goes through class_name1.

Comment: You still have not specified what you expect the behavior to be when you :`b.function_name2_1()` given that `function_name2_1` is a method on an entirely different class.

Comment: I would want it to print 'Something.' Actually, I have many functions defined in File_name2 and I want to control each of these functions in individual programs depending on the instance and in File_name1 I have to do some generic initialization.

Comment: I thought by using __init__.py, variable b could inherit class_name2 but don't know how or even if it is possible or if there are any other ways to work around this!